# Detect if library is build independently or as application dependency with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project has the following structure:

```
--\Project
  --\Library Module A
  --\Library Module B    
  --\Library Module C    
  --\Application Module
```

I´m using [android-fat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar), to merge all library modules into one single aar for other projects, which works like a charm.

To test my library, I have also an application module, which includes the library.

After upgrading to the latest gradle version and fat-aar version, building the application module is impossible

[Github Issue - com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define ...](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar/issues/51)

To merge **Library Module B** and **Library Module C** into **A**, I have to declare those dependencies as **embedded** instead of **compile**.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:10.0.1')
    embedded project(':Library-Module-B')
    embedded project(':Library-Module-C')
}
```

As I mentioned, this works when I build the library independently, but not if I build the application module.

I don´t know why this error happens, because none of those libraries gets included more than one time according to the log output, so I thought coming up with a small workaround would do the trick:

1. Check if library is build independently or not
2. Change embedded to compile if true (because then it works again) OR add all embedded dependencies to the default dependency set in fat-aar

Is it possible to let the library detect, if the library is build independently, or if the application is built together with the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could simply solve it by using an ext-property

Therefore I´m setting it in the **application module**

```
android {
    rootProject.ext.set("applicationBuild", true)
    compileSdkVersion 23
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and in the **submodule**

```
  boolean applicationBuild = rootProject.hasProperty("applicationBuild")

  if (!applicationBuild) {
     embedded .....
     embedded .....
     embedded .....
  }else{
     compile ....
     compile ....
     compile ....
  }
```

The property is only set when I build the application module

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not really familiar with building Android libraries with Gradle, (and never heard of `android-fat-aar`, I cannot say whether there is a better solution that works properly, so maybe someone else can come up with something.

To do the detection you have in mind, you can e. g. use `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { }` and in there check the taskGraph for the presence of the application tasks. The `taskGraph` represents the tasks that will be executed in this build, which is the explicitly specified ones (or `defaultTasks` if none) and all their dependencies.

But actually afair this point in time should be after the configuration phase, so might be too late to change whether a dependency is `compile` or `embedded`. But it might be just in time to change the fat-aar configuration like you suggested. Just play with it and see how you get it to work from within the `whenReady` closure.

Comment: Thank you. I´ve tried to add the embedded dependencies in the afterEvaluate method to the compile dependencies and it seems to work. The problem is, if I want a cleaner solution (modifying the fat-aar) I cannot hardcode my application module name. There must be a solution to somehow get information about the module, which starts the build process

Comment: In the `afterEvaluate`? I didn't say anything about `afterEvaluate`. How do you do your check there, the `taskGraph` might not be ready at this point. A module does not start a build process, you start the build process, by calling some task to execute. Which tasks are to be executed and thus checking whether the application gets built or not I described in my answer already. Maybe you could also think about separating your application module from your library modules, making the application module standalone and using the library like any other application would too.